# How to merge json objects based on a common value using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have a following json payload where some have same key-value pair. I want to merge those objects if they have same key-value pair using dataweave

Input:

```
[
    {
      "id": "123",
      "phoneNumber": "123456789",
      "mobileNumber": "987654321",
      "email": "abc@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "234",
      "custID": "123451234"
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "user": "user1"
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
      "id": "123",
      "phoneNumber": "123456789",
      "mobileNumber": "987654321",
      "email": "abc@abc.com",
      "user": "user1"
    },
    {
      "id": "234",
      "custID": "123451234"
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can group by id, extract the groups and map each one depending on the number of items per group. If more than one you can use reduce to create a single object but we need to remove the duplicated "id" keys.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.id)
    pluck ((value, key, index) ->  value)
    map (if (sizeOf($)>1) 
        $ reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator - "id" ++ (item))
        else $[0]
    )
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "phoneNumber": "123456789",
    "mobileNumber": "987654321",
    "email": "abc@abc.com",
    "id": "123",
    "user": "user1"
  },
  {
    "id": "234",
    "custID": "123451234"
  }
]
```